# Strategy for web caching

Tags: mongodb, caching, nginx, distributed-caching, database

so i have some pages to cache, around 5 million.

1. Pages very rarely updated
2. I want to serve it by nginx
3. Its impossible to use File System for caching because of different servers.

I need some independent database or NetFS or some thing else, It must be visible for Nginx to serve static, and backend can control cache on it.

At the moment i look on mongodb gridfs, but i'm not sure is it good choice. And it have few unpleasant restrictions.

What is the best scalable database for the static files?

Comment: Sounds more like an administrator/webmaster sort of question (not very programming related?)

Comment: At the moment i test MongoDb Gridfs + nginx-gridfs  (Nginx module for serving files from MongoDB's GridFS.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the problem is what you've described it as then I think you're making the problem more complex than it is. Static pages are exactly that: static. Nginx does fantastically well at serving static files. If you require a caching layer above that then look into [Varnish](https://www.varnish-cache.org/). I'd suggest revisiting using just a regular file system and after testing, consider tuning and optimizing your file system and storage to improve performance.

Comment: Nginx is Server_1 Backend generate static files on Server_2 how i can transfer it or make visible to Server_1?

Comment: You could have a live mirroring/deployment service synchronizing the files among all the backend servers, network mount a share across each server, or even use a distributed file system made for the task. Above all else, start with something simple and then test the performance of the setup using real (or simulated) traffic to get an accurate estimate of what your requirements are and what works for your deployment.

Comment: OK, if some one update his page, i need to change cache file. It looks like i must check all 5 million cache files and if one of them changed move it to frontend server cache. That if i use some thing like rdiff. I sure it be not so fast, and how i can return updatet page to user if Server_1 still have old cache?

Comment: I think you've misunderstood the problem. Caching and serving files are two separate problems. Serving static files is what Nginx does best. Caching and distribution of whole pages is what Varnish does best. Test and benchmark your traffic and then plan accordingly. If you really need multiple Nginx+Varnish servers in order to serve static files, you're likely doing something really, really wrong.

Comment: Most of pages generated by backend, does not changed for long time, 3-7 month. Thats why i want create it static version to remove load from server, page generation coast is really big. For another i use memcached.

Comment: Disconnect your site-build service from your production web servers. If the files really are static, then serving them though an Nginx+Varnish pair should be straightforward. Whenever you need to update the site, generate the pages and rsync them up to the production servers.

Comment: I want to build this structure with 4 servers.  1-Frontend(Nginx) 2-Backend(Lighttpd+fcgi) 3-Worker, 4-Worker. 2-Backend do all small jobs and light load calculations, all high load jobs it gives to workers. What i done understand how to make a bridge between 1 and 2 servers.

Comment: Is it good idea to try Amazon Simple Storage Service (Amazon S3) like static files cache system?

Comment: Do what you want to do. IMHO, four servers for this is overkill. At best, I'd start with one or two. I don't think that you need four independent servers to serve cached, static files.

Comment: "four servers for this is overkill" for static files of course;) Only one (1-nginx) server for static. Another three do another job. Anyway i didn't see good way for serve large collections of static files. And really good way to control this collection.